# How to prevent users from deleting commit from remote git repository

Tags: git, gitolite

I have a git remote repository setup on a shared hosting service with access to git over https. I want to prevent some or all developers from deleting commits from remote repository. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **[gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html)** specifically, you have [different types of permissions](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#write-types).
They include a 'D' for deletion:

```
repo @all
    RWCD dummy-branch = foo
```

That will authorize the deletion of a branch `dummy-branch`, but that will *also* make all your existing `RW+` rule *deny* deletion (because they don't have a '`D`')

> If a rule specifies `RWD` or `RW+D`, then rules that do NOT have the `D` qualifier will no longer permit deleting a ref.

In that case, you specify who has the right to delete, the others, by default, won't have that right.

Comment: hmm so it seems using gitolite it is possible. Is there no way in default git without gitolite? If so I think I will have to move my repository to gitolite. The gitolite permissions system is not very clear in first read, but I guess I get the idea.

Comment: @DivKis01 No: gitolite is made to authorize. Git itself is just there to manage the repo content (history), it does not manage authentication or authorization. Other Git repos managers offers similar services, like GitLab and its protected branches:  https://help.github.com/articles/about-protected-branches